# Rails: query the existence of a join table's child

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Setup:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sales
  has_many :sold_items, through: :sales, source: item
  has_many :returns, through: sold_items
end

class Sale < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :item
  has_one :return
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sales
  has_many :returned_sales, through: :sales, source: :return
end

class Return < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sale
end
```

**Question:**

Edit: Clarify question. I want all Items not return by a given user.

Hint: Items may have may Sales scoped to a User: If an Item has two sales, one returned and one not, I *don't* want to show that Item.

```
user_items = user.sold_items.distinct
goal = user_items.reject {|i| i.returned_sales.first}
```

This does not work because it queries all returned_sales for items, not just the ones scoped to the user.

---

*Edit:* adding Return association `has_one :returned_item, through: :sale, source: :item` and querying

```
returned_items = user.returns.map {|r| r.item}
goal = user_items - returned_items
```

does the trick but is not sexy: single query preferred.

Comment: You want a left anti-join, i.e. find all sold items, do a left join to find items returned by that user, and in the where clause keep only the rows where the  right hand side is null. Another option is to use `NOT EXISTS` with a subquery. I don't speak Rails/ActiveRecord, so I can't translate that from SQL into Rails-speak, but hopefully that sets you on the right track.

Comment: @CraigRinger Thanks, I am looking for Items not returned by a user, not unreturned sales (please see my edit)

Answer (score 0):

On the Sale:

```
def self.not_returned
  where.not(Return.where("returns.sale_id = sales.id").exists)
end
```

Then you can:

```
Sale.not_returned
```

Comment: Maybe my question was not well worded. I want all Items not returned by a given user. (Items may have many sales scoped to a user: if an item has two sales, one returned and one not, I don't want to show that item.)

Comment: So given an instance of User, show all items bought by that user for which the user has never returned that item on any of the user's sales?